# Additional separation between require and algorithm

Tags: captions, algorithms

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
...
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A good name}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \REQUIRE something usefull
    \STATE $i \leftarrow 1$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

This works fine but there is only a line above and below the algorithm and between the caption and require. Is it possible to add an additional line 
between require and the first statemenent because it looks confusing especially 
if the requirement is long?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [adjust spacing of algorithm float caption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11274/adjust-spacing-of-algorithm-float-caption)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Line after `Require`:

To add a horizontal line after the `Require` you can use `\hrule`:

[image]

or a `rule`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A good name}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \REQUIRE something useful \vspace{4pt}\hrule\vspace{5pt}
    \STATE $i \leftarrow 1$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A good name}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \REQUIRE something useful \vspace{4pt}\par\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vspace{5pt}
    \STATE $i \leftarrow 1$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

---

### Alternative Solution:

A better alternative might be to use `\rule` and incorporate the solution form [Adjust spacing of algorithm float caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11274/adjust-spacing-of-algorithm-float-caption), which uses `\DeclareCaptionFormat` from the `caption` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{algorithm}{\vspace{0ex}{%
  \parbox[c][1.75em][c]{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}\par\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{format=algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A good name}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \REQUIRE something usefull \vspace{4pt}\par\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vspace{5pt}
    \STATE $i \leftarrow 1$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want an additional line between require and the first statemenet not additional space for the caption. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @joachim: have updated solution to add a horizontal line.